# Run python script for existing docker image in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, docker, visual-studio-code, pipenv

I have an existing docker folder (folder with python script, that has `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yaml`) - that runs fine if I run it directly via docker. I want to be able to run docker under `Visual Studio Code`, so when I change code in the script in `VSCode` - it rebuilds and reruns the script right in the docker (and I hope it does this fast)

I have installed `Remote-Containers` plugin for `VSCode`, opened folder as container, and rebuilt container. The container seems to be built and I can access it in terminal - and it works if I run everything manually in the terminal, but I experience issues in `VSCode`:

1. Every time I rebuilt the container, I have to install Python plugin on it in VSCode (it asks this on F5). This is an inconvenience but would be nice for VSCode to solve this automatically.
2. `Dockerfile` has commands:
   `RUN pipenv install` and `RUN cp config.sample.py config.py` These seem to not execute in the container. If I run them manually in the terminal - I can proceed, but of course, I expect VSCode to do that.
3. `Dockerfile` also has command:
   `CMD ["pipenv", "run", "python", "fp.py"]` I want this to be executed on `F5`. Instead, VS code just runs `/use/bin/env /user/local/bin/python fp.py` - that misses all the env. Ideally would be nice to be able to debug it on `F5`. I cannot select `pipenv` as interpreter.
4. I have doubts all of this executes `docker-compose.yaml`. Not sure I really need it, but if I can somehow include it in the pipeline, would be awesome - but I might be wrong and it is already executing

My `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.8

RUN python3.8 -m pip install --upgrade pip && \
pip3 install pipenv

WORKDIR /app

COPY Pipfile* ./
RUN pipenv install

COPY . .

RUN cp config.sample.py config.py

CMD ["pipenv", "run", "python", "fp.py"]
```

There is a lot of new to me here, so I might be doing this in a stupid way - the goal for me to set up VSCode, so I can easily develop this script, under container.

My `launch.json` is empty - not really sure what to write there.

Comment: Is it actually important to use a container here; can you set up a non-container Docker virtual environment, without Docker, and use that for day-to-day development?  If you install [pipenv](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) you should be able to run `pipenv install` to create it from the `Pipfile` that's checked in to the source tree.

Comment: @DavidMaze You are probably right for this situation, but I would really like to figure out the container setup. I have a big list of containers (the python one is just the first one) - so I would really like to figure out, how to do this container-way

Answer (score 0):

I think more or less I figured it out. I was mostly confused by the existence of `docker-compose.yaml` that didn't work, but I found out that the team doesn't really use it and it is actually expected.

I still have to do a lot to run it, but it runs OK now, so I am 50% happy. My process:

1. Open folder `VS Code`
2. Rebuild container
3. Run in terminal (on the container): `pipenv install`. This will create env that will be displayed in VS later - it is not in the list if `pipenv` was not installed
4. F5
5. Install Python plugin in the container
6. Select pipenv environment (there is a lot of text in the name and pipenv is mentioned in the end of it, pretty easy to confuse it with other envs)
7. Now I can use F5 to run my code